# How to read / write data into a S25FL064L flash memory?

Tags: spi, flash-memories, nordic

I try to read / write data (single byte) into an `S25FL064L` SPI flash memory with an nRF52 based radio SoC. The datasheet says that I have to enable a write to nonvolatile memory by sending command code `0x06` and then I can use command code `0x12` to transmit up to 256 bytes to a given address.

```
// Write Enable for Nonvolatile data
Tx_Buffer[0] = S25FL064L_CMD_WRITE_ENABLE;
p_Device->p_CS(true);
p_Device->p_RW(&Tx_Buffer[0], 1, NULL, 0);
p_Device->p_CS(false);

// Read status register 1 -> will return 0x02 = write is enabled
uint8_t Rx_Buffer[2];
Tx_Buffer[0] = S25FL064L_CMD_RDSR1;
p_Device->p_CS(true);
p_Device->p_RW(&Tx_Buffer[0], 1, Rx_Buffer, 2);
p_Device->p_CS(false);

Tx_Buffer[0] = S25FL064L_CMD_4PP;
Tx_Buffer[1] = 0x00;
Tx_Buffer[2] = 0x00;
Tx_Buffer[3] = 0x00;
Tx_Buffer[4] = 0x00;
Tx_Buffer[5] = 0xF0;
Tx_Buffer[6] = 0xAA;

// Transmit the data
p_Device->p_CS(true);
p_Device->p_RW(Tx_Buffer, 7, NULL, 0);
p_Device->p_CS(false);

S25FL064L_WaitBusy(p_Device);
```

I just have to send the command code `0x13` to read the data from a given address:

```
Tx_Buffer[0] = S25FL064L_CMD_4READ;
Tx_Buffer[1] = 0x00;
Tx_Buffer[2] = 0x00;
Tx_Buffer[3] = 0x00;
Tx_Buffer[4] = 0x00;
p_Device->p_CS(true);
p_Device->p_RW(Tx_Buffer, 5, Rx_Buffer, 7);
p_Device->p_CS(false);
```

But the flash doesn´t transmit the data.

**Write command**
[image]

**Read command**
[image]

What might be wrong here?

Comment: What data is already in the Flash memory at the address you're accessing? Have you erased it so that it starts at 0xFF?

Comment: Found the problem. I had to erase the flash first.